# Sprite of icons into icon font

Tags: css, fonts, icons

I have a sprite of about 30 icons. I'd like to convert these icons into an icon font on icomoon.io. I only have the png sprite file. What is the best and most efficient way to convert a sprite into an icon font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creating a font from a png most likely a bad idea, **png** is a pixel format so you will not be able to scale the font.

the most efficient way to create a font is using **svg**, which can be converted to any font format and is scalable

There is a good tool called [**Font Custom**](http://fontcustom.com/) to create icon fonts, which export's to any font format